# Unlocked bootloader with OEM locked inside system in Oneplus3. HELP?

Tags: rooting, bootloader, unbricking, locked-out, unrooting

I have a OnePlus3 device which was rooted(TWRP + magisk + stock rom). But as new rom was buggy, i install old stock rom + stock recovery without root. After installing by mistake i lock OEM from the developer menu. Now after a restart, I stuck in the bootloader. Now, bootloader can't be locked or can't install new recovery. I can access bootloader and recovery but can't get into System. I tried to sideload rom but it keeps loading.What to do now?

Comment: Can you see your device from adb/fastboot?

Comment: yes but can't install new recovery or rom.

Comment: headline says *unlocked bootloader* question says *bootloader can't be locked* please edit

Answer (score -1):

Boot to bootloader, unlock oem and start the process all over again. You need to flash a recovery first, then the full ROM.zip.

If this doesn't work or you can't get it right, use the unbrick tool. We can provide you with the links if you can confirm your device

Comment: OP wrote "After installing by mistake i lock OEM from the developer menu". You can't unlock bootloader using fastboot unless you permit OEM unlocking from developer options (unless of course, vendor messed up lock/unlock implementation).